# Clone/Sync Github Repo to Visual Studio current project using Github EXT for VS?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm still new to this whole Github and Git thing, so I was wondering how to do this. I have sync/push my current Visual Studio project to Github and created a new repo for it.

After I do my coding and such, I would push all the changes to Github using the Visual Studio Git tool.

My question is, let's say I mess up something really bad and I need to "revert" back to the good version that I just pushed earlier, how can I do that? How can I sync my local project with the one on Github using the Visual Studio Git Ext tool?

Another question I have is, how can I create like a test branch to mess with, and when I have done something I want to push to the master branch, I can just push it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with VS Git plugins, but i can help you with the command line git tools.

To create a new branch, simply use

git checkout -b [branch name]

This will set your HEAD to the newly created branch, if you want to push on that branch, use :

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Commit message here"
git push
```

Then, when you're satisfied you can merge back to the master branch using :

```
git checkout master
git merge [your branch name]
```

And to revert to an older commit :

```
git revert <commit hash>
```

Relevant documentation :

https://code.likeagirl.io/how-to-undo-the-last-commit-393e7db2840b?gi=522d5bdbae34

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: I should probably learn the command-line as well so this is helpful, thank you!